# close weaviate client ts nodejs

Tags: jestjs, weaviate

I was looking for a way to close a weaviate client in nodejs typescript as I need to do this so I can implement a jest test

I have looked in the index.d.ts and could not find any function that would close a weaviateClient

this is the error I am recieving

```
Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting:

  ●  TCPWRAP

      33 | );
      34 |
    > 35 | export const weaviateClient = weaviate.client({
         |                                        ^
      36 |   scheme: 'https',
      37 |   host: process.env.WEAVIATE_HOST!,
      38 |   headers: {'X-Cohere-Api-Key': process.env.COHERE_KEY!}
```

but after diving into the source code I do not see and open handles unless I am mistaken thus it MAYBE a problem with something else